# An alternative way to say a "bioprotective suit"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, synonyms

I am looking for short ways to describe special suits one uses in a case of a virus outbreak.

I have already found: chem-bio suit, bioprotective suit, bio protective suit, biohazard suit, chem-bio suit, bio-protective gear, hazmat suit.

Any other suggestion that would be usable in American English?

Does anyone know of a site with a thesaurus, which is specialized in two or more words synonyms?

Comment: You already have seven of them, why do you need more? Hazmat suit, which is pretty much the shortest way to say hazardous material suit, is the most common usage I've heard.

Comment: In British English and some American commando novels there's the term "kitted out" which refers to any set of clothing for a particular purpose.  That may be a substitute for "suit" which is a little serious for a thriller, which I assume is what's going on here.

Comment: @John As in my other posts, it is for a script, which usually goes for 60-100 pages. Since these guys pop up all over the story, I need as many different expression as I can find.

Comment: @Syk If that's the case, then I suggest you actually make up a name for them. Like "whitesuits" (just identify what those are first) so that the reader can identify what you or the characters are talking about without having to think on it too much. This will also let you define a clear meaning and not have to worry about skewing it with different words.

Comment: The three-letter-initialism PPE is slowly entering the American vernacular, standing for [Personal Protective Equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_protective_equipment).  The caveat is that PPE when said by sailors on a ship, it means something different than PPE when said by electrical line workers, or soldiers in combat, or doctors entering a quarantine zone, etc.  Within a group, the term will probably be understood, but could be confused when different groups discuss.

Comment: You might want to ask about this issue on [Writers SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) or even [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). It sounds like you are looking for synonyms to spice up your dialogue, but I would think changing the terminology for a particular piece of equipment all the time would be more likely to just confuse the audience.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something short and snappy, as opposed to technically more accurate, many people would recognize **space suit** as appropriate is this context.

E.g. see those visually striking scenes in the movie ET when the "experts" move in, with their apparel making them so ironically alien, arriving as they are into what was a domestic setting, albeit one harbouring an *actual* alien.

Comment: I did not intend to use this one, but you brought me to an idea how to build it into my story.
Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear it was useful @Syk.  So, please feel free to upvote or mark as accepted if you wish.

Comment: I did it. Just so we are clear - I did not down-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

**Positive pressure personnel suits (PPPS)** — or positive pressure protective suits, informally known as "**space suits**", "**moon suits**", "**blue suits**", etc. — are highly specialized, totally encapsulating, industrial protection garments worn only within special biocontainment or maximum containment (BSL-4) laboratory facilities. These facilities research dangerous pathogens which are highly infectious and may have no treatments or vaccines available.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_pressure_personnel_suit)